# How to convert Vec<Result<Option<(u32, u32)>, Error>> to Result<HashMap<u32, 32>, Error> using iterator only(without for)?

Tags: rust

Apologize for confusing title.

Say I have a `user_ids: Vec<u32>` and there is a function `fn get_year(user_id: u32) -> Result<Option<u32>, Error>`(this function involve db lookup`

And I would like to get years of all those user_ids and concert it into a hashmap where key is the id and value is the year. If it should return error immediately if there is one `get_year` return error.

I am able to get it working with `for`

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    ConnectionFail
}

fn get_year(user_id: u32) -> Result<Option<u32>, Error> {
    Err(Error::ConnectionFail)
}

fn get_age_lookup(user_ids: Vec<u32>) -> Result<HashMap<u32, u32>, Error> {
    let mut age_lookup = HashMap::new();
    for &user_id in user_ids.iter() {
        let year_result = get_year(user_id)?;
        match year_result {
            None => (),
            Some(year) => {age_lookup.insert(user_id, year);}
        };
    };
            
    Ok(age_lookup)
}


fn main() {
    let age_lookup = get_age_lookup(vec![1, 2, 3]);

    println!("result: {:?}!", age_lookup);
}
```

But not able to do it without `for. I am able to get it working but that require 2 iterators which is probably not efficient. I wonder if there is a way to make it work with only 1 iteration without` for`?

```
fn get_age_lookup(user_ids: Vec<u32>) -> Result<HashMap<u32, u32>, Error> {
    let age_tuples =
        user_ids
        .into_iter()
         .map(|user_id| {
                    get_year(user_id)
                        .map(|year_result| match year_result {
                            None => None,
                            Some(year) => Some((user_id, year))
                        })
            })
            .collect::<Result<Vec<Option<(u32, u32)>>, Error>>()?;
            
    Ok(age_tuples.into_iter().filter_map(|x| x).collect::<HashMap<u32, u32>>())
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. The missing ingredient here is `Result::transpose()`, which turns a `Result<Option<T>, E>` into a `Option<Result<T, E>>`.  You can `filter_map()` over that, which will eliminate the `Ok(None)` values and simultaneously unwrap the nested `Option`, so you'll have an iterator of `Result<T, E>` at that point.  Finally, `collect()` can convert into a collection wrapped by a `Result` -- if any item in the sequence is `Err`, it will short-circuit and propagate the error.

```
fn get_age_lookup(user_ids: Vec<u32>) -> Result<HashMap<u32, u32>, Error> {
    user_ids
    .into_iter()
    .map(|user_id| {
        get_year(user_id)
        .map(|year_result| match year_result {
            None => None,
            Some(year) => Some((user_id, year))
        })
    })
    .filter_map(|x| x.transpose())
    .collect()
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7924983fe5fda5037ca9b82beb3fc494))

---

As an aside, you can additionally simplify your `match` using the `Option::map()` method, which applies a transformation to `Ok` values.  So this:

```
match year_result {
    None => None,
    Some(year) => Some((user_id, year))
}
```

Can become:

```
year_result.map(|year| (user_id, year))
```

Comment: Thank you. it works well. May I ask for this example, would you say it's slightly cleaner to just use `for` instead of more functional style(with mutation)?

Comment: @bruteforcecat My personal preference would be the iterator-based approach. I tend to avoid loops over collections when possible, as most such loops aim to reshape the collection in some way, which is usually easily expressed as a chain of iterator calls. Once you are familiar with the basic iterator transformations (map, filter, reduce) it becomes second nature to prefer them over loops. If you return an iterator instead of a vector, they are even more preferable as they are lazily-evaluated -- the caller may only need a portion of the results.

Comment: @bruteforcecat In your example, if you accept an `IntoIterator` and return an `impl Iterator` then your function becomes considerably more flexible. For example, if the caller needs only the first 5 elements then you don't have to waste time and memory on all the other elements. Further, if the first 5 elements are `Ok` and the 6th is `Err`, the caller would actually be able to use the first 5 and stop reading, whereas with this code the caller will only get the `Err` out due to the `.collect()` call.

Comment: @bruteforcecat In this case, returning an iterator doesn't make a lot of sense since the purpose is to build a mapping, but you could have the function accept `impl IntoIterator<Item=u32>` then the caller can still pass in a `Vec<u32>` but they can also pass in anything that can be turned into an iterator of u32 -- including an iterator.